# Given arbitrary real number $x>1 , y>0$ prove that there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x^{n-1} \leq y < x^{n}.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Given arbitrary real number $x>1 , y>0$ prove that there exists $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that: $$x^{n-1} \leq y < x^{n}.$$

Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Did you try taking logarithms?  The natural logarithm is a monotone increasing function on the positive reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y\geq1$, then look at the sequence $1,x,x^2,\ldots$. It is increasing, and diverges to infinity, so at *some point*, it must be larger than $y$. Let $n$ be the smallest natural number such that $x^n>y$.

If $y<1$, do a similar thing with $1,\frac1{x},\frac{1}{x^2},\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
n = \lfloor\log_x y\rfloor + 1
$$
Then
$$
x^n > x^{\log_x y} = y
$$
because $\log_x y < \lfloor \log_x y\rfloor + 1$ and
$$
x^{n-1} = x^{\lfloor \log_x y\rfloor} \leq x ^{\log_x y} = y
$$